# Creating a Batch file for Converting Video Formats using Handbake

Tags: video, batch-file, transcoding

I am trying to write a batch script that converts .wma videos into .mov using handbrake

This is what I have tried but it seems to not working.

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('DIR /B /S *.wma') DO "C:\Program Files\Handbrake\HandBrakeCLI" -i "%%G" -o "%%G".mov --preset="Normal"
```

I have set the preset to normal since I would like to play the video on my pc.

Thanks

Comment: Is your question related to operating Handbrake or to creating a batch file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your output name is formatted incorrectly.

Try `-o "%%~dpnG.mov"` ...

Full command:

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('DIR /B /S *.wma') DO "C:\Program Files\Handbrake\HandBrakeCLI" -i "%%G" -o "%%~dpnG.mov" --preset="Normal"
```